# Set element height from another element in Angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have two divs in a section which contains dynamic content. The left container contains a list of numbers and the other one list of input fields. I need to prioritize container of input fields if that container stretches out to 600px of height, I need to have that height on my number container and then that element goes into separate scroll if its longer than 600px.

[Example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV9tG.png)

[Code example](https://codepen.io/drobke/pen/pVVEOz)

```
<section>
  <div class="numbers">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>

  </div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">

  </div>

</section>

section {
  display: flex;
}
.numbers {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.numbers div {
  background: black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
  input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Please show what you've done, so other can help.

Comment: I added image of my problem

Comment: @AlonEitan I added the code

Comment: could you tolerate a fixed height? 600px like you mentioned in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem, i made a function that is called in Oninit and every button that updates the content and on html i called it  `[style.height.px]="elHeight - 100"`

This is my Typescript code

```
  getHeight() {
        const leftEl = document.getElementById('number-col');
        const rightEl = document.getElementById('question-col');

        setTimeout(() => {
          this.elHeight = rightEl.clientHeight;
        }, 100);


      }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div #getElementHeight>
          Height
    </div>
    <div [style.height.px]="getElementHeight.offsetHeight" class="rect-side-line">
      Height of this element is {{ getElementHeight.offsetHeight }}
    </div>
```

as per this you can get height of first div and set it to second div.

Answer (score 0):

adaptating a div height in javascript or in angulaJS seems to me a wrong choice, so i tried to do that in css, and that is a *not so clean* solution

```
section{
  padding-left:40px;
  position:relative;
}
.numbers{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  max-height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
}
```

this seems to work but there are plenty of other ways to do that: bootstrap, tables, grid, flex, anything you already use in your html in order to keep consistent.

Comment: didn't saw you were already using flexboxes, my bad, but you now have the main idea, stackoverflow is all about showing us what you have tried and failed rather than asking for code writing ;) good luck